# Spotify plugin has disappeared in the Clementine Music Player on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, clementine, spotify

I have a premium Spotify account and wish to use this account via the Clementine Music Player 1.1.1. program. But when I go to the Configure Spotify tab in that program, the plugin is stated as `not installed` and there's also no option to do so.

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 2):

I Finally got the plugin to be recognized by Clementine.

Adding to coteyrs answer, here is what I did:

1. Create the folder where the plugin will be placed

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.config/Clementine/spotifyblob/version14-64bit
   ```
2. Download the plugin

   ```
   cd ~/.config/Clementine/spotifyblob/version14-64bit
   wget http://spotify.clementine-player.org/version14-64bit/blob
   wget http://spotify.clementine-player.org/version14-64bit/libspotify.so.12.1.45
   ```
3. Make sure the executable bit is set on the blob

   ```
   chmod +x blob
   ```
4. The blob was looking for libspotify.12, so we create a symlink

   ```
   ln -s libspotify.so.12.1.45 libspotify.so.12
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Direct from [the clementine site](http://www.clementine-player.org/downloads)..

You can download the latest version of Clementine on Ubuntu from the official PPA.

Run these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:me-davidsansome/clementine
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clementine
```

You will need to do this if you want the latest (or non-open) features.

Once you have updated if your still missing the plugin download button you can install manually. [Instructions are here](http://spotify.clementine-player.org/README). You can download the plugin from [this directory](http://spotify.clementine-player.org/).  Just put the blob and the plugin in `~/.config/Clementine/spotifyblob`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have the latest version of Clementine and have run the commands you suggested but the option to install the plugin is still not there.

Comment: There is a download button for me. Clicking this button allows me to download see http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18875117/Preferences_074.png

Comment: Is that 1.1.1 and are you in ubuntu 13.04? If so then I'. At a loss. No plugin option on mine :-(

Comment: make the preferences window bigger? Maybe it is cut off?

Comment: No, even fullscreen it's not there... http://ubuntuone.com/3IhnyeIqqekFh5Y1nocLYL

Comment: I added instructions for manually installing. Please make sure you are using the version from clementine repo (uninstall and re-install jsut to make sure) before you try. You might also want to make sure that directory is empty before you start the manual process.

Comment: Hi Coteyr, thanks for your help, I've done all that's suggested above but still no joy :-( To be fair, the only distro I've seen it work as standard is in Fuduntu... Not sure where to go from here but your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Further to this... I have tried mint, suse, elementary and Clementine has the spotify install button in all of these after installing from ppa. I cannot believe I'm the only person having this issue?

Comment: Further edit: All 13.04 based distributions are missing the ability to download the Spotify plugin in clementine 1.1 - Very disappointing - but from the thin information i have seen on this, this is due to a legal issue.

Comment: If anyone is following this, here is a fix. http://xeizo.com/blogg/?p=563