# Sennheiser MM 400: How to use headset controls

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headset, spotify

I've successfully connected my Sennheiser MM400 bluetooth headset, and it's playing everything over them. Now I'm using spotify to listen to music, and I tought it would be nice to control spotify via the controls on the right side of the headset.

Only problem: While volume keys (up and down) do work, I can't use the previous and next keys (left and right). When I press one of them, the following appears on my screen:
[image]

Anyone got an idea how I could make the controls work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you observe indicates that these controls are not implemented in your Spotify client.

Media key control via a Bluetooth headset is transmitted via DBus MPRIS protocol to the player to be further processed there.

You can test this by running Rhythmbox which should have a full implementation of the MPRIS standard (but unforutnately a [Spotify plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135072/how-to-install-rhythmbox-spotify-plugin) seems not easy to get). On my system here I am able to control the Rhythmbox playback including fast forward and rewind buttons from a Bluetooth headset. But I am unable to do so with a player that does not support MPRIS (e.g. Audacious) where I also get the warning sign you posted in your question.

You may need a fully MPRIS complatible media player that comes with a Spotify plugin. You may try if [Clementine](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clementine) [image: Install clementine] meets your needs.

Sadly however in 13.04 the Clementine Spotify plugin seems to be no [longer supported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289439/spotify-plugin-has-disappeared-in-the-clementine-music-player-on-ubuntu-13-04) so you will need an earlier Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

You coul also try installing the remuco-plugin for clementine:

`sudo apt-get install remuco-clementine`

Worked for me on a Philips SHB9100WT, maybe works also for Sennheiser heapphones?

But beware, you have to press the pause-button 2 times
(see: https://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/issues/detail?id=712 for details).

Hope that can help you.